# Удалить значение в ячейке TableView в которой используется делегат, при этом чтобы поле ячейки осталось пустое

Tags: python, pyqt, tableview

Как добиться того, чтобы **при удалении** значения в ячейке в которой используется делегат SpinBox, **зафиксировать поле пустым**.

По такому алгоритм:

-Двойной клик по ячейке -появляется значение SpinBox по умолчанию

-Нажимаю **Del** - удаляется значение, поле ячейки пустое

-Нажимаю Enter - ячейка  должна остаться пустая.

Минимальный пример

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyledItemDelegate, QSpinBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QModelIndex) 

class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    signal_delegate = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, int)  

    def createEditor(self, parent, options, index):
        editor = QSpinBox(parent)
        editor.valueChanged.connect(lambda val, row=index.row(): self.update_editor(val, row))  
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        try:
            value = index.model().data(index, Qt.EditRole)
            editor.setValue(int(value))
        except TypeError:
        pass

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, options, index):
        editor.setGeometry(options.rect)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        value = str(editor.value())
        model.setData(index, value, Qt.EditRole)

    def update_editor(self, val, row):  
        self.signal_delegate.emit(val, row)  


class MyDelegateInTableView(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()           
        self.sim = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(1,1) 
        self.table.setModel(self.sim)

        boxMain = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        boxMain.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(boxMain)

        delegate = Delegate(self)                                             
        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)

       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    windowExample = MyDelegateInTableView()
    windowExample.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Посмотрите что находится в методе `setModelData`, в переменной value после ввода

Comment: @Alexander Chernin - Не могу понять вашего намека.  'SetModelData()' - Функция считывает содержимое spin box и записывает его в модель" - то есть,  это конечный результат работы делегата. Из spinBox я удаляю значение, то есть value пустое должно передаваться в setModelData, но отображается  последнее введенное значение. Что не так, в модели?

Comment: `то есть value пустое должно передаваться` - оно пустое?

Comment: @Alexander Chernin, получается что нет,  раз в итоге оно остается не удаленное. При первом запуске, в SetEditor , value None - поле пустое. Нажимаю Esc  - пустое поле сохраняется. После update_editor , нажимаю Del, несмотря что поле визуально пустое, последнее введенное значение сохраняется. Я пересмотрел множество примеров с делегатом, и везде одно и то же, после удаления, ячейка пустая уже не будет. Мне трудно понять, как решить мой вопрос.

Comment: Смотрите, я вижу три пути. 1. Наследовать QSpinBox и отслеживать нажатие кнопки Del для очистки поля от данных и, соответственно, передача пустого значения в модель (через сигнал). 2 создание составного виджета для ячейки, состоящего из QSpinBox и кнопки "Х", отвечающей за очистку значения в модели (клик по кнопке - очистка значения в модели) 3. Попробовать QLineEdit с валидатором на числа, вместо QSpinBox